# How can a table from the Glue Catalog raise NullPointerException?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I'm currently trying to join two tables together in AWS Glue from a RDS instance and after successfully crawling the database structure I'm setting up my job with:

```
table1 = (
    glueContext.create_dynamic_frame
    .from_catalog(database="transact", table_name="transact_table1")
)
table1.printSchema()
print "Count: ", table1.count()

table2 = (
    glueContext.create_dynamic_frame
    .from_catalog(database="transact", table_name="transact_table2")
)
table2.printSchema()
print "Count: ", table2.count()
```

Strangely, the job fails with:

```
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1520463557704_0008/container_1520463557704_0008_01_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/dynamicframe.py", line 275, in count
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1520463557704_0008/container_1520463557704_0008_01_000001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1520463557704_0008/container_1520463557704_0008_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1520463557704_0008/container_1520463557704_0008_01_000001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o64.count.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 4.0 (TID 26, ip-10-1-2-4.ec2.internal, executor 1): java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$13.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:427)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$13.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:425)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:286)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:268)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:126)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
```

The curious part is that it only happens in the **second** `count()`, because I can see in the logs that it correctly prints out the `table1` schema and count. **And it also prints the `table2` schema.**

I did this because I was trying to `Join.apply` those dynamic frames together and it was failing with `NullPointerException` too. What gives? Am I missing a bit of configuration perhaps?

**UPDATE 1**:
It appears that it's a problem with that second table in particular. Picking some other table from the catalog to serve as `table2` makes the Job succeed.

So I'll morph the question into: *how must a table from the catalog be different from the others that makes it raise this error*?

Answer (score 0):

```
print "Count: ", table2count()
```

is it a typo error while posting the question to SO, if not please check the code ?  Shouldn't it be **table2.count()** ?

Comment: Yes, it's a typo in the question. (Had to minify the example). Thanks, I'll fix it.

Comment: Can you accept the answer or upvote on my answer, if it helped on initial question. thx